# append information into a log file from a bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to pull all the information to a log file using:

this is written inside my bash script.

```
exec >> (tee -a "$log")
```

but this actually shows all the output and brings all the information to the log file.
can you don't show 1 line of the output inside the bash script?

Comment: What do you mean by _output **inside**_, vs. _**all** the output_? Your command simply ensures that from now on, all stdout goes to `tee`.

Comment: exec >> $log
commend 1
commend 2

causes the output in the page not showing up, after i tee. it all came out in the terminal page. But i didn't want everything to shown.

Comment: In this case, `tee` is the wrong tool: It copies the stdout to a file, and also to its own stdout. Why don't you simply redirect everything to a file? And why doing this from **inside** the script, instead of letting the invoker decide?